# Ruby gems: Cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi i'm trying to install some gems, but when I do i get the error

ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.

so when I do the command gem install bundler I get this:

:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in`'

It happens every time I try to do something with gems...I'm new at this, so I would appreciate some help...I've search a lot but instead of solving the problem I keep getting deeper

Answer (score -2):

I'm having a similar problem when I try to install some gems, I think it is because rubygems.org is down.
Check this: ["Could not find a valid gem in any repository" (rubygame and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962051/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-in-any-repository-rubygame-and-others)
Check tomorrow if you can install it.

Comment: This error message is very different form that of the OP. it is very likely to be a different problem.