# Can't install Jekyll on Windows 10 x64

Tags: ruby, windows-10, jekyll

I've been trying to install Jekyll. I enter the following command:

```
gem install jekyll bundler
```

I receive error messages:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0) in any repository
>
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0) in any repository

My system: Windows 10 x64

```
ruby -v:
```

> ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

```
gem -v:
```

> 2.5.2

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962051/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-in-any-repository-rubygame-and-others ? Note the comment about SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if you have any source configure:

```
# gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org
```

If not, please add the rubsgems source with

```
# gem sources -add https://rubygems.org
```

You should also perform an update of rubygems:

```
# gem update --system
```