# Problems installing SASS in cygwin

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, cygwin

I am following the course CS50's Web Programming with Python and JavaScript and we have to use SASS among other tools. I installed cygwin in my windows and has been working fine for almost everything (git, atom, etc.) but now I am trying to install SASS with no success. I follow this instructions: https://gist.github.com/Geraint/1600659 and they seem to work fine. The only problem is that the link to the RubyGems instructions seems to be broken. Still, it seems to me that I do have ruby and gem.

When I try the command:

```
$ gem install sass
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'Autorizado/bin' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: authorizable, authorization, authorization-san, auto_admin, auto_ria_api
WARNING:  You don't have /home/Usuario in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/Usuario Autorizado/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby.exe -I /usr/share/rubygems -r ./siteconf20200324-1935-rt56xf.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/Usuario Autorizado/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/Usuario Autorizado/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/2.6.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

Here is also a screen shot, I think it has something to do with my PATH but I have not been able to find a solution. My current folder has two - words (Usuario Autorizado) I do not know it this is also a problem and how to solve it.

[Screen Shot of my cygwin terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLf5m.png)

I already tried this:

```
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
```

Explained here: ["Could not find a valid gem in any repository" (rubygame and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962051/could-not-find-a-valid-gem-in-any-repository-rubygame-and-others) but it did not work.

I would really appreciate any help...

Comment: Change the path so there are no spaces in it. (rename `Usuario Autorizado` to `UsuarioAutorizado`)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You may be able to get this working, but you should be aware that Ruby Sass is no longer supported: "Ruby Sass was the original implementation of Sass, but it reached its end of life as of 26 March 2019. It's no longer supported, and Ruby Sass users should migrate to another implementation." https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass

SassC is a supported implementation available as a gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby

Comment: Hi @PatrickBrinich-Langlois thanks for your answer. I just want to install SASS no matter if Ruby or other implementation. Would you know how I can install SASS easier? I mean, maybe without Ruby of RubyGem, just SASS from the cygwin terminal. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know how to safely rename the directory. I don't use Windows, I don't use Cygwin. Neither is a suitable solution for using Ruby. If you're stuck on Windows, you should be using WSL as your solution to running Linux, not Cygwin.

Comment: Thanks @anothermh I would learn more about WSL and maybe give it a try

Comment: You are trying to install the `ruby` version of `sass` package, and that is already available as cygwin package. Use Cygwin setup and install `ruby-sass`. Installing the latest version without ruby is another question and it seems you lack Know How on general building of packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @matzeri, this solved my problem and now I can use sass in the cygwin terminal. Yes, I am just learning this topics.